# "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used" error

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I am making a simple university module database system that involves updating and navigating through various modules for various courses. I have 'Next', 'Previous', 'First' and 'Last' buttons to navigate through the modules and their fields which are assigned to textboxes which uses a dataset of the module table. I have successfully managed to do this but when I try to use a oleDbCommand to select the tutor's forename and surname from a different table using the tutor ID linking the two tables. When I click the button the first time I only get the module details from the module table and no data about the tutor forename or surname. On the second click I get a "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used." error and on the third click I get the tutor forename and surname and everything works fine. This has confused me as the button seems to only work on clicks of multiples of 3. Does anyone know why this is happening?
Here is the code:

```
private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rownumber = 0;
        ShowProducts();


        string tutorID = datasetModuleInstanceUSB1.Module.Rows[rownumber]["TutorID"].ToString();

        try
        {

            //Open connection
            oleDbConnectionModule.Open();

            //Define connection for command
            oleDbCommandGetTutorName.Connection = oleDbConnectionModule;

            //Define data reader to be used
             OleDbDataReader dR;
            dR = oleDbCommandGetTutorName.ExecuteReader();

            //Set parameter for get tutor name ID

            oleDbCommandGetTutorName.Parameters[0].Value = tutorID;



            if (dR.Read())
            {

                txtboxTutorForename.Text = dR["Forename"].ToString();
                txtboxTutorSurname.Text = dR["Surname"].ToString();

                //Execute get tutor name command
                ;
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            //Close connection
            oleDbConnectionModule.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: I seem to have fixed this with disposing the connection in the finally statement. But I am now getting a "The connectionString property has not been initialized" error. I have checked my oleDbconnection and the connection string is there. Does anyone know what it is?